# How to apply changes to elements of a tensor/vector without changing its reference?

Tags: machine-learning, lua, neural-network, conv-neural-network, torch

I am sharing parameters of a network and want to apply some operations to change to the elements of the parameter vector. I cannot do those operations directly on the parameter tensor because they will certainly change the parameter vector reference and sharing breaks. So **:clone()** the shared parameters vector and apply the changes I want on the new vector and use the **:copy()** function to replace the elements in the original parameter vector. I thought the **tensor:copy()** function does not change the vector/tensor reference but it seems that it does since the parameter sharing collapses soon after apply it. So I wonder, can anyone fix the code below and suggest a way to change the elements of the parameter vector without breaking the sharing?

```
tempParam = parameters:clone()
Do some operations on the tempParam vector
parameters:copy(tempParam) -- Do the replacement (the copy() function breaks the sharing)
```

One of the operations I'm interested in doing is clamping but the clamp() function also breaks the sharing if applied directly kon the parameter vector.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need a pointer to the Tensor that will modify its raw data, preserve the reference and sharing. This link (Tensor doc) clearly explains it.
https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#result-datatensor-asnumber